# Do some check before http subscribe Angular

Tags: angular, http

I need to check if a JWT is expired before make any http call. What is the best way to do that?

At the moment I'm using the interceptor to make the control for every request, but if the JWT is expired I get an exception because the interceptor doesn't return the request because of the redirect.

Comment: `Interceptor` is the best place to do that, you can catch the error, `create token` and can `resend` that

Comment: It was obvious, why did not I think about it before? :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to handle **`JWT expiry`** using **`Interceptor`**

**Steps to follow:**

1. Create an `interceptor` to `intercept` the `requests`
2. Handle the error from api using `next.handle(req).catch`
3. Check the status of the error and send a specific status code for
    `token expiry`
4. Call the `create token` method and add that token to `headers` or
    `formdata`
5. Recall the request using `next.handle(newReq)`

**Interceptor:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpParams
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

import { YourService } from './your.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private yourService: YourService) { }
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle(req).catch((event): any => {
      if (event instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (
          event.status == 'some status for token expiry'
        ) {
          return this.yourService.createToken().flatMap((res: any): any => {
              const token = res.data.ws_token;
              // send something with token and send request again   
              // set headers
               let headers = new Headers();
               headers.append('Authorization', token);
              const newReq = req.clone();
              return next.handle(newReq)
          }, err => {
            console.log(err)
              return Observable.throw(event);
          });

        }
      } else {
        return Observable.throw(event);
      }
      return Observable.throw(event);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: If that's actually a quote, please provide a source. If not, don't format it as one. And please don't use `inline code` for generic emphasis.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, removed the quote, thnx

Comment: @Federico Xella, check that? any issue you are facing?

Comment: Nice! I'll give a try as soon as possible, thank you!